# How to boot Mx Linux 19.3 when it failed after an update?

Tags: debian, boot, mx-linux

Today 28/11/2020 Following Commands were executed in MX linux 19.3 KDE Environment after which screen went black and reboot started but wont boot correctly.

1 sudo apt update

2 configuring apache cassandra source file in /etc/apt/source some directory

3 running configure file of python 3.8.6 present home directory

Here youtube link of Boot process
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5SKGPCFBBs

When accessed root directory for MX through Other Distro, it showed new and old initrd.img and vmlinuz.

In Win 10 there was Intel Update for Win 10 Version 20H2

Comment: Before the splash screen, can you see if your boot line has "hush" or "quiet take it out and give us a screenshot so we can see the error? Watching the whole video was a bit hard.

Comment: As well, holy booting images batman, what are you using as your boot manager? you need to see the full boot line.

Comment: Hello Mark Scheck, Flash Screen Shows, [2.6890281] psmouse seriol: synaptics: unable to query device: -5. But Earlier Flash Screen also used to show some comments about UEFI.

Comment: Anyone having authority of closing this question can do that cause somehow mx booted back and works fine now. Thank You Mark Scheck for your time and guidence.